# host network solutions domain on an amazon ec-2 box

Tags: amazon-ec2, hosting

I have looked this up and what was described in other answers did not work for me. I created a elastic ip from my ec-2 dashboard, and I set the A records of my domain (www, *, and @(none)) but it does not work. When I try to go directly to the ip address it also does not work though so I am not sure why this is happening.

Also where exactly does the elastic ip point? To my home folder, to the ec-2 user? It is not working now so I couldn't test it, but when it does work I still won't know.

Comment: What are you trying to serve from your machine? The elastic IP just points at the machine (well, instance), not to any specific service on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things: remember that your domain will need to propagate, so leave it a few hours. Also, your elastic IP points to the machine you bound it to.

Almost forgot, you also need to edit your security zone to open up ports to allow incoming connections on those ports, as the default is to block everything except SSH.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. But how do I edit the security zone? How can I allow browser access?

Comment: The security zones are under security zones, just choose the one which is applied to your instance. To allow browser access, you'll need to set up Apache (httpd) on the box. It's outside the scope of this comment box, but googling for "Apache tutorial" should point you in the right direction. You might want mod_userdir too to host files from a folder in a user's home directory.

Comment: I have apache set up on the box. I have my httpd folder with conf files and all that set up. I also allowed http and dns access to the security group, but I still got nothing.

Comment: Is the domain actually resolving to your EC2 instance?

Comment: It says it is. I have it set to an elastic ip I set up though. I tried to just ping the ip address though and I don't get any response

Comment: You might need to open the port in the security zone to allow ICMP packets through, I can't remember the port number off the top of my head though.

Comment: still no luck. I appreciate all your help though

Comment: It sounds like your security zone is set up wrong. Apart from that, I don't know what else to suggest, sorry!